# html form with multiple submitbuttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have 2 submit buttons in an HTML form.

How can I know which submit button has triggered the JavaScript function?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function verifyData(formdata) {

        // Here I want to know from which submit button this function is triggered

        // I can't use type button instead of submit

        // I can't use onclick handler

        //  I can't use JQuery.. I want to do only with                 javascript                        

    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="verifyData(this);" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit2">
</form>

<button value="delete row" id="but1" onclick="disps()">delete row</button>
```

I want to do different actions based on the different submit buttons clicked.

Comment: What different actions do you want to perform? You could simply check the value on the server if you give the input the same name <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit1">

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to check the button clicked through the onsubmit event. Instead move the call to `verifyData()` to the `onclick` handler of each button. Use `return` in the `onclick` call to cancel submission if false is returned by `verifyData()`

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function verifyData(button) {
        // validate
        switch (button.value) {
            case "submit1":
                // do somehting
                break;
            case "submit2":
                // do somehting
                break;

            // ...
        };

        // submit the form
        return true;
    }
</script>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit1" onclick="return verifyData(this);">
    <input type="submit" value="submit2" onclick="return verifyData(this);">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about putting an onclick event handler on both buttons which will set a variable to say which button was clicked?
like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function verifyData(formdata) {
        alert(btnClicked);
        // Here I want to know from which submit button this function is triggered

        // I can't use type button instead of submit

    }

    var btnClicked = 0;


    function setSubmit(which) {
        btnClicked = which;  return true;
    }
</script>

<form onsubmit="verifyData(this);" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit1" onclick="return setSubmit(1);">
    <input type="submit" value="submit2" onclick="return setSubmit(2);">
</form>
```

Comment: thats fine... But I can't use the onclick handler to my applicn.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library?

If you can using this you can easily bind to each submit button based on an `id`.

For example:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit1" id="submit1">
    <input type="submit" value="submit2" id="submit2" >
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#submit1").click(function(e)
    {
     // Do stuff when 1 is clicked.
     $("#form1").submit();
    });
    $("#submit2").click(function(e)
    {
     // Do stuff when 2 is clicked.
     $("#form1").submit();
    });    
</script>
```

you could also have the buttons as a type of `button` to avoid any issues, but you should be able to simply `return false;` to stop the button of type `submit` from... submitting

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it... Firstly I would use jQuery so you must include that in your document like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It would also mean your HTML can be simplified to:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="submit1"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit2"/>
</form>
```

Then you can use jQuery:

```
<script>
    // When the document is ready
    $(function(){
        // Action performed when a submit button in the form is clicked
        $("form[type='submit']").click(function(e){

            // Get the value attribute
            var val = $(this).val(),
            validation_has_passed = false;

            // If it is submit1
            if(val == "submit1") {
                // Validate submit 1
                validation_has_passed = true;

            // If it is submit2
            } else if(val == "submit2") {
                // Validate submit 2
                validation_has_passed = true;

            }

            // If all validation is OK submit the form
            if(validation_has_passed === true) {
                $("form").submit();
            }

            // Ensure pressing these buttons doesn't submit the form
            e.preventDefault();

        });
    });
</script>
```